# Unable to uninstall managed package

Tags: managed-package, uninstall

We installed a zendesk package and while trying to uninstall it I get the following error:

> Component is in use by another component in your organization. SalesEdgeEltWorkflow

I get this error for every custom field that the package installed. The package is inactive. What could be causing this issue? I've looked in all my workflow rules and process builder processes and still no clue.

Comment: try to find this component "SalesEdgeEltWorkflow" maybe some old deactivate workflow or process builder.

Answer (score 2):

SalesEdgeEltWorkflow is related to the dataflow function in Einstein Analytics (formerly Wave Analytics).  If you're not using Wave, you can clear out the dataflow by uploading a blank JSON file.  See this old [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000egsJQAQ).

Comment: Known issue says it's fixed everywhere. Weird

Comment: @Eric I found that known issue a while back but for me it seems to be not fixed.